# converting a batch file to a shell script

Tags: shell, batch-file

Can anyone please help me with this? I've got a .jar file for which I wrote a batch file (code is shown below). How do I create an equivalent shell script?

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    set BUILD_LIB_DIR=lib
    set CLASSPATH=.
    for %%f in (%BUILD_LIB_DIR%\*.jar)do set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%f
    java -client -cp %CLASSPATH% -jar -Dport=7000 MyJar.jar
ENDLOCAL
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with scripting on Windows (I infer you are using Windows from the backslash.), but I thought I'd offer the following anyway.  This should work on a Unix/Linux workalike system. It is a bash script.

Create script file with following content and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash

BUILD_LIB_DIR=lib
CLASSPATH=.
for f in $BUILD_LIB_DIR/*.jar; do
    CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH;$f"
done
java -client -cp $CLASSPATH -jar -Dport=7000 MyJar.jar
```